# How can I return an integer to 2 significant figures in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, integer, return-value

I have been trying to figure out ways to return an integer value and convert it to 2 significant figures. Here is a description of my problem.

I have a method called `getValue()` which returns an instance variable of type int called `value`. 
Now, within the method definition of a separate class, I want to call the method `getValue()` with the value returned being 2 significant figures (1 will be 01, 2 will be 02 etc).

Here is my rather messy attempt:

```
return (String.format("%02d",(hours.getValue().toString()))+":"+String.format("%02d", (hours.getValue().toString())));
```

`hours` and `minutes` are instance variables of that separate class.

When I run a separate test program, I get an error saying `ClockDisplay.java:32: error: int cannot be dereferenced`. Following this error, I tried changing the return type of the method `getValue()` to String but I still get some weird error.

Could someone please help me do this?
Thanks

Comment: Two significant figures means having no more than two leading non-zero digits e.g. 1234 => 1200 and 1.234 => 1.2  In you case hours and minutes cannot have more than 2 significant digits.  I assume you means zero padded numbers for a minimum of two digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need hours.getValue().toString(), you just need hours.getValue() because you specified "%d" which means it needs an Integer. As you said, hours.getValue() will return an integer, so there is no need to say .toString() (if you think u r converting it to string that way).

Answer (score 0):

return (String.format("%02d",Integer.valueOf(hours.getValue())));

Answer (score 0):

To print hh:mm format you can do

```
return String.format("%02d:%02d", hours.getValue(), minutes.getValue());
```